# How can I generate a row_number without using a window function?

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, how do you generate a row number:

- WITHOUT a Window Function (like [row_number()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html))
- WITHOUT a Temp Table
- Only using a single `SELECT`

Here is some sample data to play with,

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo AS 
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
  ('wgates', 'Gates', 'William' ),
  ('wgrant', 'Grant', 'Wallace' ),
  ('jjones', 'Jones', 'John' ),
  ('psmith', 'Smith', 'Paul' )
) AS t(name_id, last_name, first_name);
```

The desired output would be:

```
 row_number │ name_id │ last_name │ first_name 
────────────┼─────────┼───────────┼────────────
          1 │ wgates  │ Gates     │ William
          2 │ wgrant  │ Grant     │ Wallace
          3 │ jjones  │ Jones     │ John
          4 │ psmith  │ Smith     │ Paul
```

Some of these methods can get tricky. Please explain your answers. I can also imagine two categories of answers that work:

- data with a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` (we can still use `name_id` here)
- nothing `UNIQUE` at all.

All features are on the table for the most recent version of PostgreSQL.

Ultimately, I need a unique key on a table that has no ID so I can update it against a cross-join of itself. I am also asking out of simple curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `UNIQUE` Column Required

One approach I found (in [SIMULATING ROW NUMBER IN POSTGRESQL PRE 8.4](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?url=archives/79-Simulating-Row-Number-in-PostgreSQL-Pre-8.4.html) by Leo Hsu and Regina Obe), is called the *"The all in one WTF"*. It's been slightly adapted, but it's amazing.

```
SELECT row_number, name_id, last_name, first_name
FROM people
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT array_agg(name_id ORDER BY last_name, first_name) AS id FROM people
) AS oldids
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, (SELECT count(*) FROM people))
  AS gs(row_number)
WHERE id[row_number] = people.name_id;
```

So let's go down the rabbit hole:

1. Create an `ARRAY[]` of any specific column, generating no additional rows.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM people
   CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT array_agg(name_id ORDER BY last_name, first_name) AS id
     FROM people
   ) AS oldids;
   ```

   ```
    name_id │ last_name │ first_name │              id               
   ─────────┼───────────┼────────────┼───────────────────────────────
    jjones  │ Jones     │ John       │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith}
    psmith  │ Smith     │ Paul       │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith}
    wgates  │ Gates     │ William    │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith}
    wgrant  │ Grant     │ Wallace    │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith}
   ```
2. Create a Cartesian product with a `generate_series(1..last_row)`. In order to get the last row, we do a subselect with `count()`.

   ```
    SELECT *
    FROM people
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT array_agg(name_id ORDER BY last_name, first_name) AS id FROM people
    ) AS oldids
    CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, (SELECT count(*) FROM people))
      AS gs(row_number);
   ```

   ```
     name_id │ last_name │ first_name │              id               │ row_number 
    ─────────┼───────────┼────────────┼───────────────────────────────┼────────────
     jjones  │ Jones     │ John       │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          1
     psmith  │ Smith     │ Paul       │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          1
     wgates  │ Gates     │ William    │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          1
     wgrant  │ Grant     │ Wallace    │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          1
     jjones  │ Jones     │ John       │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          2
     psmith  │ Smith     │ Paul       │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          2
     wgates  │ Gates     │ William    │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          2
     wgrant  │ Grant     │ Wallace    │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          2
     jjones  │ Jones     │ John       │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          3
     psmith  │ Smith     │ Paul       │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          3
     wgates  │ Gates     │ William    │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          3
     wgrant  │ Grant     │ Wallace    │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          3
     jjones  │ Jones     │ John       │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          4
     psmith  │ Smith     │ Paul       │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          4
     wgates  │ Gates     │ William    │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          4
     wgrant  │ Grant     │ Wallace    │ {wgates,wgrant,jjones,psmith} │          4
   ```
3. Now comes the magic, we use the row number as index into the array we created. Because the array is a function of: (a) The `UNIQUE` column and (b) the order in the set, we can reduce the cartesian product, and preserve the row_number. All we do is add the clause `WHERE id[row_number] = people.name_id;`

Answer (score 10):

> *identify a good technical PK for duplicate removal*

Now that is a completely different question then finding a workaround for `row_number()`.

In Postgres you can use `ctid` for that. No need for window functions or slow and non-scalable workarounds.

---

To answer the direct question:

This *can* be done without window functions, but this is going to be horribly slow:

```
select name_id, last_name, first_name, 
       (select count(*)
        from the_table t2
        where t2.name_id <= t1.name_id) as row_number
from the_table t1
order by name_id;
```

The above is identical to:

```
select name_id, last_name, first_name, 
       row_number() over (order by name_id) as row_number
from the_table
order by name_id;
```

But the solution with a window function **will** be a **lot** faster. If you don't need any ordering, then use

```
select name_id, last_name, first_name, 
       row_number() over () as row_number
from the_table
order by name_id;
```

You won't get a "stable" row number that way, but it **will** be unique.

Another possible alternative is to create a sequence, then use `nextval()` in the select statement.

Comment: It's not identical, `<=` provides `rank()`, not `row_number()`

Answer (score 8):

If it is performance you are worried about, use `row_number` without `order by` to avoid sorting.

```
row_number() over ()
```

Answer (score 1):

## No `UNIQUE` column required, but a unique ordering must be possible

This method requires *no single unique column* but it requires a unique order. This is effectively the window version of `rank()` and not `row_number()`; however, `rank()` is `row_number()` if you can get a unique ordering. I based this approach on [SIMULATING ROW NUMBER IN POSTGRESQL PRE 8.4](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?url=archives/79-Simulating-Row-Number-in-PostgreSQL-Pre-8.4.html) by Leo Hsu and Regina Obe, it's listed as the "cross-platform method."

```
SELECT (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people
  WHERE 
  (COALESCE(people.last_name,'') || COALESCE(people.first_name,'')) <= 
  (COALESCE(oldtable.last_name,'') || COALESCE(oldtable.first_name,''))
) AS row_number,
  oldtable.*
FROM people AS oldtable
ORDER BY oldtable.last_name, oldtable.first_name;
```

In the comments of that page, we can find a slightly simplified version made pg-specific with

```
SELECT (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people
  WHERE 
  ROW(people.last_name, people.first_name) <= 
  ROW(oldtable.last_name,first_name)
) AS row_number,
  oldtable.*
FROM people AS oldtable
ORDER BY oldtable.last_name, oldtable.first_name;
```

There really is no elegant way to break this down... We have a

```
SELECT oldtable.*
FROM people AS oldtable
ORDER BY oldtable.last_name, oldtable.first_name;
```

Now we're going to do a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` that compares how many rows are `<=` the current row.

- In the first example, we do the comparison with the database-agnostic method of concatenating columns to create something that should *likely* makes unique.
- In the second example, we do the comparison with the [PostgreSQL specific `ROW()` constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html)

It's not an easy query to break down, but we can construct a simpler table.

```
CREATE TABLE foobar AS
SELECT x FROM generate_series(1,10)
  AS t(x) ORDER BY random();

SELECT
  x,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM foobar AS f2 WHERE f2.x <= f1.x)
FROM foobar AS f1
ORDER BY x;
```

In this example we again

1. take an unordered set that provides for a unique ordering
2. order the set
3. compare it with itself to see how many rows are `<=` the current row.

Here would be the output of the above simplified example. We're only simplifying by providing a single column with a unique order (rather than composite-ordering, and bypassing the protection against nulls). As another aside, if rows are unique by a left-to-right ordering of the columns, we can compare `ROW(people.*) <= ROW(oldtable.*)`

```
 x  | count 
----+-------
  1 |     1
  2 |     2
  3 |     3
  4 |     4
  5 |     5
  6 |     6
  7 |     7
  8 |     8
  9 |     9
 10 |    10
```